# Expandable Gridview is not showing the full content

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am using `Expandable GridView` which doesn't scroll the whole content if grid items are changed dynamically.

Below is the xml code for main gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="135dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/titles"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            style="@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <fone.adipoli.shopping.ExpandableHeightGridView

        android:id="@+id/gridView_shopping"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:background="#fff"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"

        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Xml for each Grid item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardrow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_row1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             />
</LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_row1_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_row1_model"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

            android:visibility="gone" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_row1_price_offr"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_row1_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="10sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_row1_product"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buy_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="BUY"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:textAppearance="? android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I tried adding a view in the bottom after `GridView` ,but it doesn't work out.

Any help would be really thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`
or 
    `ScrollView`

Put your whole Grid items in `NestedScrollView`, or `ScrollView` seems to solve your problem.